# Class of all σ-fields containing a class

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

given a set $ \Omega   = \{0,1,2\}$  and a class $A = \{\{1\}\}$, what is the class of **all  σ-fields** containing $A$

Methink it is $2^\Omega$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $2^\Omega$ is the wrong kind of thing -- that's a set of sets of numbers, whereas a set of $\sigma$-algebras would be a *set of sets of sets* of numbers.

The correct solution cannot be written down quite as simply as your proposal, but on the other hand it's easy to work out *explicitly* by hand. One of the $\sigma$-algebras is (of course) $2^\Omega$ and there's only one other.

Comment: $\{\{\emptyset, \Omega\}\} $?

Comment: @Bachelier: $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra alright, but it does not have your $A$ as a subset. So it shouldn't be a member of your class. But $2^\Omega$ should, as I noted.

Comment: OK. Let me work it out. thanks

Comment: I think it would be $\{\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \{\{1\}\} , \{\{1\}\}^c\}$ with $ \{\{1\}\}^c = \mathcal{P}(\Omega) \setminus A $

Comment: So my class would be $ \{ \{\mathcal{P}(\Omega)\}, \{\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \{\{1\}\} , \{\{1\}^c\}\} $

Comment: Edit to comment #3:  
The correct set is $ \{\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \{\{1\}\} , \{\{1\}^c\} $ with $  \{\{1\}^c\} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega) \setminus A $ edit reason: $A^c$ is wrong.

Comment: @Bachelier: $\{1\}^\complement = \{2,3\}$, so $\{\{1\}^\complement\}=\{\{2,3\}\}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. $2^\Omega\setminus A$ is a diferent set, but is not a $\sigma$-algebra either, because it contains $\{2,3\}$ but not its complement. Finally, neither $\varnothing$ nor $\{\{1\}\}$ are $\sigma$-algebras either.

Comment: so the answer would be: The first sigma algebra is $\sigma_{1}(A) = 2^\Omega$
$ \ $  And the second one is: $\sigma_{2}(A) = \{ \emptyset, 2^\Omega, A, A^c \}$

Comment: Is $A^c =\{\{0,2\}\}?$

Comment: Is $A^c =\{\{0,2\}\}?$ with respect to what set is this complement taken?

Comment: I think I got it: $\sigma_{2}(A) = \{\emptyset, \Omega, A, A^c \}$ with $A^c = \{\{0,2\}\}$

Comment: One last question, would the $ \mathcal{P}(A)$ be the smallest algebra for this set?

Comment: @Bachelier: Whoops sorry, I mistakenly remembered $\Omega$ as $\{1,2,3\}$ rather than $\{0,1,2\}$. Your $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ look _almost_ fine now, except that it should be $\{\varnothing,\Omega,\{1\},\{1\}^\complement\}$ instead of $\{\varnothing,\Omega,A,A^\complement\}$. Remember that $A=\{\{1\}\}$, which is not the same thing as $\{1\}$!

Comment: $\mathcal P(A)$ is in itself an algebra, like all power sets are -- but it is not an algebra _on $\Omega$_, so it's not really relevant here.

Comment: oops..I meant $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ instead of $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a better understanding of this tricky concept. You got to appreciate set theory. A theory that requires rabbinical study and observation to understand its deep concepts.

Comment: @Bachelier: Ah. $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ is the _largest_ algebra on $\Omega$, that is, the one that contains the most sets. We can also call it the _most fine-grained_ algebra.

Comment: True. If $\Omega$ was the set $\{0,1\}$, with the same $A$ as defined in the question, then we would have only one algebra. The power set of $\Omega$. Right?

Comment: @Bachelier: Right.